# Why cant Python 3.x find my imports? (relative or absolute)

Tags: python, import

I'm going to preface this with the fact that I inherited this code and still learning about Python's imports.  I tried adding relative paths, absolute paths, and started appending folders to my sys path (which I learned is very bad to do).  There seems to be an inconsistency with the way everyone successfully declares paths in Python and the way I declare paths, and when I ask most tell me "well, it just works" or they're not sure why *my* imports do not work.  So, any discussion on best practices would be appreciated though not necessary to answer the question.

This app is *apparently* supposed to work without any edits.  I have a docker container with a folder structure like so:

```
     - app
        - sim
           - __init__.py
           - notebook.ipynb
        - src
           - __init__.py
           - model.py
           - factory.py
           - utils.py
```

Within `notebook`, I try to import a function from `model.py` using:

```
sys.path.append("../")
sys.path.append("../src")
from src.model import some_fcn
```

This throws an error: `module 'src' has no attribute 'utils'` because `src.utils` imports `factory`.  Full trace:

```
<ipython-input-2-a807>
---> 14 from model import some_fcn

/app/src/model.py in <module>
     11 import copy
     12 
---> 13 import src.utils as utils

/app/src/utils.py in <module>
     14 import scipy
---> 15 import src.factory
     17 import src.model as model

/app/src/factory.py in <module>
      7 import numpy as np
----> 8 import src.utils as utils
      9
```

Its worth noting that the *original* notebook had

```
sys.path.append("../") 
from model import some_fcn
```

and I have no idea how this used to work because there's no way that model.py would be found!  Weird.

In summary, the nested imports cause errors.  This is not the first time I've run into these nested import problems and I have no idea how to work around them, if its a problem with my docker, or if its a problem with my setup.  Does the project require restructuring?  How did this EVER work?  How can I make it work?  I am actively trying to avoid making edits to their code, but this has become a regular occurrence and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What Python version are you on? You've got a circular import there, and those are always going to cause problems, but different Python versions handle this a bit differently.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Python 3.6.12

Comment: Try something newer - the handling for this particular case changed in (I believe) 3.7.